# Why could MS graph explorer and my python request results be different even request details are the same

Tags: python, rest, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I'm using ms-graph `user:findMeetingTimes` api in order to retrieve free meeting times of given user.

I have used `https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer` with `POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/findMeetingTimes` to retrieve free meeting times and I used Python `requests` module to retrieve the same information with same parameters, but results are incorrect when calling with python `requests` then in `graph-explorer`. Access rights are as provided in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-findmeetingtimes?view=graph-rest-1.0). What for me it looks that `"meetingDuration": "PT1H"` doesn't work when calling rest from Python api and then it returns by default every 30 mins as it's described in `user:findMeetingTimes` documentation. Has anyone had this issue?

**The only difference is `start/end` times. I'm expecting `start/end` would be 1h (setting with `"meetingDuration": "PT1H"`) but instead it returns 30mins as by default**

This is not an issue if I'm using `graph-explorer` that Microsoft gives for testing, but the issue comes when I'm calling from my Python api...

**The request-body:**

```
{
  "attendees": [
    {
      "emailAddress": {
        "address": "<user-email>",
        "name": "<user>"
      },
      "type": "Required"
    }
  ],
  "timeConstraint": {
    "timeslots": [
      {
        "start": {
          "dateTime": "2019-01-24T19:00",
          "timeZone": "AUS Eastern Standard Time"
        },
        "end": {
          "dateTime": "2019-01-24T21:00",
          "timeZone": "AUS Eastern Standard Time"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "meetingDuration": "PT1H"
  }
```

**request-headers:**

```
 {'return-client-request-id': 'true', 'client-request-id': '<client-id>', 'Authorization': 'Bearer <token>', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Prefer': 'outlook.timezone="AUS Eastern Standard Time"', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'User-Agent': 'appointments/1.0'}
```

**I expect result like this:**

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#microsoft.graph.meetingTimeSuggestionsResult",
    "emptySuggestionsReason": "",
    "meetingTimeSuggestions": [
        {
            "confidence": 100,
            "organizerAvailability": "free",
            "meetingTimeSlot": {
                "start": {
                    "dateTime": "2019-01-24T19:00:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "AUS Eastern Standard Time"
                },
                "end": {
                    "dateTime": "2019-01-24T20:00:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "AUS Eastern Standard Time"
                }
            },
            "attendeeAvailability": [],
            "locations": []
        },
        {
            "confidence": 100,
            "organizerAvailability": "free",
            "meetingTimeSlot": {
                "start": {
                    "dateTime": "2019-01-24T20:00:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "AUS Eastern Standard Time"
                },
                "end": {
                    "dateTime": "2019-01-24T21:00:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "AUS Eastern Standard Time"
                }
            },
            "attendeeAvailability": [],
            "locations": []
        }
    ]
}
```

**But with Python API I get this:**

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#microsoft.graph.meetingTimeSuggestionsResult",
    "emptySuggestionsReason": "",
    "meetingTimeSuggestions": [
        {
            "attendeeAvailability": [],
            "confidence": 100.0,
            "locations": [],
            "meetingTimeSlot": {
                "end": {
                    "dateTime": "2019-01-24T20:00:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "AUS Eastern Standard Time"
                },
                "start": {
                    "dateTime": "2019-01-24T19:30:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "AUS Eastern Standard Time"
                }
            },
            "organizerAvailability": "free"
        },
        {
            "attendeeAvailability": [],
            "confidence": 100.0,
            "locations": [],
            "meetingTimeSlot": {
                "end": {
                    "dateTime": "2019-01-24T20:30:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "AUS Eastern Standard Time"
                },
                "start": {
                    "dateTime": "2019-01-24T20:00:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "AUS Eastern Standard Time"
                }
            },
            "organizerAvailability": "free"
        },
        {
            "attendeeAvailability": [],
            "confidence": 100.0,
            "locations": [],
            "meetingTimeSlot": {
                "end": {
                    "dateTime": "2019-01-24T21:00:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "AUS Eastern Standard Time"
                },
                "start": {
                    "dateTime": "2019-01-24T20:30:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "AUS Eastern Standard Time"
                }
            },
            "organizerAvailability": "free"
        },
        {
            "attendeeAvailability": [],
            "confidence": 100.0,
            "locations": [],
            "meetingTimeSlot": {
                "end": {
                    "dateTime": "2019-01-24T21:30:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "AUS Eastern Standard Time"
                },
                "start": {
                    "dateTime": "2019-01-24T21:00:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "AUS Eastern Standard Time"
                }
            },
            "organizerAvailability": "free"
        },
        {
            "attendeeAvailability": [],
            "confidence": 100.0,
            "locations": [],
            "meetingTimeSlot": {
                "end": {
                    "dateTime": "2019-01-24T22:00:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "AUS Eastern Standard Time"
                },
                "start": {
                    "dateTime": "2019-01-24T21:30:00.0000000",
                    "timeZone": "AUS Eastern Standard Time"
                }
            },
            "organizerAvailability": "free"
        }
    ]
}
```

**I have checked headers in [graph-explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer)**

```
Host: graph.microsoft.com
User-Agent: <mozilla>
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer
Content-type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer <token>
Content-Length: 716
Origin: https://developer.microsoft.com
Connection: keep-alive
```

**and headers in my request:**

```
{
  "Accept": "application/json",
  "Authorization": "Bearer <token>",
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Prefer": "outlook.timezone=AUS Eastern Standard Time",
  "User-Agent": "myApp/1.0",
  "client-request-id": "<client-id>",
  "return-client-request-id": "true"
}
```

Comment: Is the only difference the order of the Properties, or could you mention, what’s the difference? We SO-Users are very lazy... ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question with exact issue ;)

Comment: Did you examine the Request with a Webdebugger to see whether the headers are really the same?

Comment: Updated with headers, they look similar to me...

Comment: As far as the headers don’t show much difference, could you also examine the request-body?

Comment: @Nikolaus I have added both request-bodys, unless there is something else that I could add?